# Table valued parameter has wrong data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have ASP .NET Web Form application with SignalR handling online notifications. Somewhere down the road of simplifying the code, I ran into an issue when stored procedure accepting whole table of connected clients as one of the input parameters for some reason inserts into result table less rows than when I just put a breakline into c# code before the query runs and launch it SQL-side myself.

It's really complicated code now spanning over multiple c# methods and sql queries, so I just want to know, why could this be an issue. I'm providing with small piece of code, that will hopefuly give you guys some ideas, cause I fresh ran out of mine, I feel like I tried everything by now to no avail.

Here is the SQL function dbo.UpdateAffectedClients I'm using in procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

RETURNS 
@Output TABLE 
(
    connectionId varchar(512),
    clientId int,
    numberOfNotifications int,
    isPatient bit
)
AS
BEGIN

    --ADDING AFFECTED CLIENTS TO OUTPUT
    --med/Instrument/Order
    IF(@typeId = 1)
    BEGIN

        --Adding doctors and patients
        INSERT INTO @Output (connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient)
        SELECT cc.connectionId, cc.clientId, COALESCE(COUNT(n.id), 0), cc.isPatient
        FROM MedOrders mo
        LEFT JOIN User2ExamRoom uer on mo.examRoomId = uer.examRoomId
        JOIN @ConnectedClients cc on (uer.userId = cc.clientId AND cc.isPatient = 0) OR (mo.patientId = cc.clientId AND cc.isPatient = 1)
        LEFT JOIN Notifications n on n.clientId = cc.clientId AND n.isPatient = cc.isPatient
        WHERE mo.id = @tableId
        GROUP BY cc.isPatient, cc.clientId, cc.connectionId
    END


    RETURN 
END
```

and here is the procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HandleNotificationsDBUpdate] 
    @ConnectedClients as SignalRConnectedClients READONLY,
    @tableId int,
    @typeId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --QUERY
    DECLARE 
    @affectedClients SignalRConnectedClients,

    @orderId int = -1,
    @meetingId int = -1,
    @messageId int = -1,

    @processed bit,
    @cancelledByPatient bit,
    @examRoomId int,
    @affectedPatientId int,

    @errorMessage varchar(MAX) = '',
    @written bit,
    @tracing varchar(2048) = ''


    --Whatever happened, the row got deleted from the table in the process and info is no longer available. 
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1* FROM MedOrders WHERE id = @tableId)
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN
    
        SET @tracing = @tracing + 'Row no longer exists in the original table. '

        --Insert to affected clients - prior to deleting from notifications, I'd lose the reference afterwards
        INSERT INTO @affectedClients (connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient)
        SELECT cc.connectionId, cc.clientId, COUNT(n.id), cc.isPatient
        FROM @ConnectedClients cc
        JOIN Notifications n on cc.clientId = n.clientId AND cc.isPatient = n.isPatient
        WHERE n.notificationTypeId = @typeId AND n.tableId = @tableId
        GROUP BY cc.isPatient, cc.clientId, cc.connectionId

        --Then delete notifications linked to it
        DELETE FROM Notifications WHERE tableId = @tableId AND notificationTypeId = @typeId

    END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @errorMessage = @errorMessage + 'Error in HandleNotificationsDBUpdate procedure, "Whatever happened, the row got deleted from the table in the process and info is no longer available" section, see line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() as varchar(4)) + '. Error message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    END CATCH

    --row is still there
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @tracing = @tracing + 'Row still exists in the original table. '

        --MED ORDER
        IF (@typeId = 1)
        BEGIN
            
            SET @tracing = @tracing + 'Its a medOrder, '

            SET @orderId = @tableId

            SET @examRoomId = (SELECT examRoomId FROM MedOrders WHERE id = @orderId)
            SET @processed = (SELECT CASE WHEN processed IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM MedOrders WHERE id = @orderId)
            SET @cancelledByPatient = (SELECT CASE WHEN cancelledByPatient IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM MedOrders WHERE id = @orderId)
        
            --not processed
            IF (@processed = 0)

            --PATIENT POSTED OR UPDATED ORDER
            BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN

                SET @tracing = @tracing + 'not processed. '

                --it's not already there (meaning patient didn't just update something)
                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Notifications WHERE notificationTypeId = @typeId AND tableId = @tableId)
                BEGIN
                
                    SET @tracing = @tracing + 'Patient is creating an order. '

                    --Insert row to notifications for each doctor (user) having this examRoom assigned
                    INSERT INTO Notifications (tableId, notificationTypeId, clientId, isPatient)
                    SELECT @tableId, @typeId, uer.userId, 0
                    FROM User2ExamRoom uer
                    WHERE uer.examRoomId = @examRoomId

                    --FUNCTION - insert into affectedClients table affected clientIds and number of their notifications
                    INSERT INTO @affectedClients (connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient)
                    SELECT connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient FROM dbo.UpdateAffectedClients(@ConnectedClients, @typeId, @tableId)

                END
            END
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                SET @errorMessage = @errorMessage + 'Error in HandleNotificationsDBUpdate procedure, MedOrder, PATIENT POSTED OR UPDATED ORDER section, see line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() as varchar(4)) + '. Error message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            END CATCH

            --processed
            ELSE
            BEGIN

                SET @tracing = @tracing + 'processed. '

                --deleting from notifications cause its been processed
                DELETE FROM Notifications
                WHERE tableId = @tableId AND notificationTypeId = @typeId

                --cancelled by patient
                IF (@cancelledByPatient = 1)

                --PATIENT REMOVED IT BEFORE APPROVAL
                BEGIN TRY
                BEGIN 

                    SET @tracing = @tracing + 'Patient cancelled the order. '

                    --FUNCTION - insert into affectedCLients table affected clientIds and number of their notifications
                    INSERT INTO @affectedClients (connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient)
                    SELECT connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient FROM dbo.UpdateAffectedClients(@ConnectedClients, @typeId, @tableId)

                END
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    SET @errorMessage = @errorMessage + 'Error in HandleNotificationsDBUpdate procedure, MedOrder, PATIENT REMOVED IT BEFORE APPROVAL section, see line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() as varchar(4)) + '. Error message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
                END CATCH

                --not cancelled by patient
                ELSE
                BEGIN

                    --DOCTOR PROCESSED ORDER
                    BEGIN TRY
                    BEGIN

                        SET @tracing = @tracing + 'Doctor processed the order. '

                        SET @affectedPatientId = (SELECT patientId FROM MedOrders WHERE id = @orderId)

                        --Insert row to notifications table for the patient that placed this order
                        INSERT INTO Notifications (tableId, notificationTypeId, clientId, isPatient)
                        VALUES (@tableId, @typeId, @affectedPatientId, 1)

                        --FUNCTION - Add affected clientIds and number of their notifications
                        INSERT INTO @affectedClients (connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient)
                        SELECT connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient FROM dbo.UpdateAffectedClients(@ConnectedClients, @typeId, @tableId)

                    END
                    END TRY
                    BEGIN CATCH
                        SET @errorMessage = @errorMessage + 'Error in HandleNotificationsDBUpdate procedure, MedOrder, DOCTOR PROCESSED ORDER section, see line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() as varchar(4)) + '. Error message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
                    END CATCH
                END
            END
        END

    
    END

    --Final selects 
    SET @written = CASE WHEN LEN(@errorMessage) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SELECT connectionId, clientId, numberOfNotifications, isPatient FROM @affectedClients
    SELECT @written as written, @errorMessage as errorMessage, @tracing as tracing

END
```

**Patient posted order** section is just fine, **Doctor processed order** doesn't return any patients, it only returns doctors in affectedClients result. As if it somehow failed JOIN or something (I used to run it in two insert statements, but managed to turn it into single one to see if that could be the issue).

C# method:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Handles any changes in notifications SQL side provided typeId (see NotificationTypes Table in SQL or comment in header of this function) and id of the updated row in respective table (tableId - could stand for orderId, messageId, taskId, etc.)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="typeId"></param>
        /// <param name="tableId"></param>
        public static Obj_NotificationDBUpdateResult HandleNotificationsDBUpdate(int typeId, int tableId)
        {
            //typeIds:
            //1: medOrder
            //2: instrumentOrder
            //3: meeting
            //4: message
            //5: task

            Obj_NotificationDBUpdateResult output = new Obj_NotificationDBUpdateResult();
            List<Obj_SignalRClientsListEntry> ConnectedClients = NotificationsHub.ConnectedClients;

            //preparing ConnectedClients as parametr to pass into stored procedure so I can easily link connectionId with clientId
            DataTable ConnectedClientsDt = new DataTable();
            ConnectedClientsDt.Columns.Add("connectionId", typeof(string));
            ConnectedClientsDt.Columns.Add("clientId", typeof(Int32));
            ConnectedClientsDt.Columns.Add("numberOfNotifications", typeof(Int32));
            ConnectedClientsDt.Columns.Add("isPatient", typeof(bool));

            foreach(Obj_SignalRClientsListEntry item in ConnectedClients)
            {
                DataRow dr = ConnectedClientsDt.NewRow();
                dr["connectionId"] = item.connectionId;
                dr["clientId"] = item.clientId;
                dr["numberOfNotifications"] = item.numberOfNotifications;
                dr["isPatient"] = item.isPatient;

                ConnectedClientsDt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            //Query
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Data.connStr);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("HandleNotificationsDBUpdate", conn))
                {
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConnectedClients", ConnectedClientsDt).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typeId", typeId);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableId", tableId);

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            output.affectedClients.Add(new Obj_SignalRClientsListEntry() 
                            { 
                                connectionId = reader["connectionId"].ToString(),
                                clientId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["clientId"]),
                                isPatient = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["isPatient"]),
                                numberOfNotifications = Convert.ToInt32(reader["numberOfNotifications"]),
                            });
                        }

                        reader.NextResult();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            output.written = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["written"]);
                            output.errorMessage = reader["errorMessage"].ToString();
                            output.tracing = reader["tracing"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            //joining the hub, providing context
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();

            //looping through each client whom we should notify
            foreach (Obj_SignalRClientsListEntry item in output.affectedClients)
            {
                //calling clients refresh function providng this number as an input
                context.Clients.Client(item.connectionId).clientRefreshNotificationsCount(item.numberOfNotifications);
            }

            return output;
        }
```

When I check (right before hubContext line) the output.affectedClients, it only shows doctors. But when I put a breakline before the SQLConnection line and run the body of the procedure provided same input as came to the c# method (see debug section at the beginning in the procedure), it returns doctors and patients just fine.

I tried switching some inserts in the procedure, putting stuff in the function directly into procedure, omitting function completely, tried to comment everything but the part with inserting into affectedClients, fiddle with ansi_nulls and those up there, tried to put them before query when I run it solo, tried to remove them from the procedure before altering, nothing.

I even put the tracing output to see exactly where it went in the procedure and it all seems legit, I have no idea why would it return just doctors.

Other than that - it's pretty neatly commented, so it should give you some idea of what's going on behind the curtain, but If you need to ask, ask, I'll try my best to answer. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE
So I narrowed the problem down to this

```
SELECT cc.connectionId, cc.clientId, 100, cc.isPatient
                        FROM @ConnectedClients cc
                        JOIN MedOrders mo on (mo.patientId = cc.clientId AND cc.isPatient = 1)
                        WHERE mo.id = @tableId
```

that **cc.isPatient** = 1 just doesn't work. For some unknown reason it doesn't recognize that 1 in @ConnectedClients (bit) as bit value. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding the correct table type name, so instead of `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConnectedClients", ConnectedClientsDt).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;` try `comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConnectedClients", SqlDbType.Structured) { value = ConnectedClientsDt, TypeName = "dbo.SignalRConnectedClients" });` Also your function header doesn't seem to match the parameters you are calling with nor with the parameters used inside the function

Comment: By the way, rather than `try... finally`  just put the connectio in a `using`. Also `catch...throw ex;` is a bad idea, it will wipe the stacktrace, instead use `throw;` (if you *really* need to catch at all)

Comment: tried modifying the C# part as you suggested. It works as before, no change. As for input to custom SQL function - it seems in order, it returns results, just not all of them.

Comment: Ok, I strapped the procedure down to just doing whats inside the function. It's not even launching the function, it's just doing the insert from select. There are no Ifs and Elses, no other conditions, just declared variables at the top and that one insert. It still just inserts doctors. Maybe the procedure has limitations to LEFT JOIN or something?

Comment: Edited - Removed commented out code - it doesn't help someone read the code if it's full of un-used commented out code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out... apparently - order of columns in the SQL User defined Table Type matters. I had last two columns switched in SQL table type and when the DataTable object arrived to the procedure, it disregarded column names from C# and just took those columns from left to right and started to fill the SQL table in the same order, therefore inserting **numberOfNotifications** to **isPatient** and vice versa. Now since you cannot have value bigger than 1 in a bit column, it treated it as 0 and the query kept failing JOINs and other stuff...

I would have never guessed this to be an issue. Why do I even bother naming columns in DataTable then?

Comment: Interesting, does this happen even when providing the `TypeName` for the parameter?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.